# Installing an npm package, but this error comes up

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

```
$ npm install sillyname
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write

removed 4 packages, and changed 1 package in 3s
```

Was installing an npm package called "sillyname", Angela Yu webdev task. Got the above error a lot of times. Let me know the solution. Please, and thank you :) (if anyone gets the reference to the dialogue)

Comment: The right place to ask may be https://github.com/TheDeveloper/sillyname/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

I was doing that work on my google drive, and that is the only thing done differently.

The installing of external node modules worked for me when I installed them in a directory which is directly in the hard drive or SSD of your PC. I am not sure about pendrives and external hard drives.

so yeah, just change the location of your document/file/folder to your local hard drive and the error won't come.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your problem be related to the NPM package manager cache or Disk Space.

1. Clear your cache:

```bash
npm cache clean --force
```

2. Update npm:

```bash
npm install -g npm
```

3. Reinstall sillyname

```bash
npm install sillyname
```

Also check your Disk space.

Comment: Facing an issue there tooXD

$ npm cache clearn --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Manipulates packages cache
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm cache add <package-spec>
npm ERR! npm cache clean [<key>]
npm ERR! npm cache ls [<name>@<version>]
npm ERR! npm cache verify
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [--cache <cache>]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Run "npm help cache" for more info