npm install mathjs throws an error message
I am trying to install mathjs using npm:
npm install mathjs

However, when I run the command I get this error message.
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EPERM: operation not permitted, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR UNKNOWN: unknown error, write
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
npm ERR! code EBADF
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -4083
npm ERR! EBADF: bad file descriptor, write

I have seen npm ERR! on npm install but there was no solution given.
I am using Node.js v20.3.0 on Windows 11.
I have edited the question since NPM install without errors on the C: drive (global install npm install -g mathjs), but throws errors on a google drive (locally G:).
So presumably all installs need to be global given the above ?

that "similar" post has nothing in common with your error! What makes you think it's at all relevant?

Try running the same with admin privileges (restart the terminal with administrator privileges). I think it is unable to write to the drive you are working in.

Looks to me like you are having file system problems. edit yea or permission problems maybe

Does this answer your question? Installing an npm package, but this error comes up

@chankruze,  okay.   i just saw in another post that installing to google drive causes the error, so i installed it globally npm install -g mathjs and that worked.  thanks.

@NicoHaase,  actually this does answer the question,  although why does npm not install to G: google drive ?

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. You haven't mentioned any drive so far. Also, did you check whether this is directly related to mathjs? Would installing any other package yield a different result?

@D.L I saw you never wanted the know the issue, you just need it to work. So you installed globally (indirectly to C: drive). Your actual issue was the drive you were working on, G:

@NicoHaase,  i will open a separate question.  The install is successful, but the intelli-sense does not work specifically for mathjs whereas it works for other modules.

Interestingly, and using the help in the comments from the original question and some additional research, the answer is this:

npm does not install to google drive G:. This creates the issue.
the solution is to use the --force flag to make (force) a local install happen.
with the above a global install is therefore not necessary.

so this works:
npm install nodejs --force

The above exposed the methods and attributes in the usual expected way.
Other alternative suggestions is to have a local copy of the google drive on the device. The above solution bypasses the need for a local copy.

Isn't this the same solution as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76841935/installing-an-npm-package-but-this-error-comes-up?

@NicoHaase,   The answer in the linked question proposes to clear cache (with the force flag) and then install globally (with the g flag). Whereas this is literally a direct install in 1 command line. So this solution is far superior...
